# If the Phoenix had been destroyed, would the Enterprise have immediately disappeared?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, star-trek-first-contact

In the movie *Star Trek: First Contact*, the Borg Queen orders Data to destroy Zefram Cochrane's ship *The Phoenix* and Data then fires three photon torpedoes at it which end up missing it. If Data would have miscalculated however and the photons torpedoes had hit the Phoenix and destroyed it, would the Enterprise have immediately disappeared since there would have been no first contact with the Vulcans and thus no creation of Starfleet in the 21st Century?

No Starfleet would have meant that the Enterprise E would have never existed and this is why it should immediately disappear. Also, the Borg would have never come to know about Earth because there would have been no contact with the Borg in the 24th Century. I'm referring to when the Enterprise D encounters the Borg Cube in the 'Q Who' episode.

Comment: Not sure this can be answered. There are different models of time travel; a splitting timeline theory would keep the Enterprise E in existence but now on a new timeline, while in modifiable history models it would disappear - how quickly would again depend on whether the writers wanted a 'ripple' or 'instantaneous' model.

Comment: Though if you accept the simultaneous existence of the Abrams movies and Star Trek: Picard, then that suggests both timelines are visible at once and would support the alternate timeline model - so the Enterprise would not have vanished (but would not be able to get back to a recognisable future).

Comment: @Michael, if what you say would have been the case then Enterprise E would have probably made contact with the Vulcans and would then likely have gone on to start Starfleet in a new alternate reality of the 21st Century.

Comment: Complete speculation by that point. Not even sure how the temporal prime directive would apply if the timeline is already diverging from the original.

Comment: This is another example of why time travel to change the past invariably makes for a story with plot holes.

Comment: Remember that in the moment before they went in the past they saw a borg filled world. In that scene, Data says "The temporal wake must somehow have protected us from the changes in the time-line" so no, the enterprise would have simply remained there. How they re-establish the future of star fleet is speculation though. But like a lot of stretches in reality in star trek, they needed the enterprise to be there, so they pulled the "somehow" card again and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on City on the Edge of Forever: the Enterprise disappeared when history changed.  Only the landing party was spared due to the Guardian's local timeline protection. DS9 "Time's Orphan" old Molly disappeared after she sent young Molly back - which made old Molly impossible.  DS9 "Children of Time" the descendants of the crashed Defiant disappear when the starship no longer crashes.

In First Contact the Enterprise-E saw the timeline change - Earth was full of Borg and the fleet disappeared - but the Enterprise was protected because it was affected by the time travel technobabble already.  I'd say based on the above examples if the timeline change became a certainty - the Enterprise would have disappeared at that point like old Molly did.  in the meantime however the universe was willing to give it a chance to succeed.  Seems like Back to the Future rules.

Comment: '...Earth was full of Borg...' I think this is another paradox because since the Borg failed in their attempt to stop First Contact due to the intervention of the Enterprise, then technically there should have never been an alternate reality which had a Borg-conquered Earth. The Earth should have remained the same as the Enterprise E went into the time warp wormhole created by the Borg sphere.

Comment: For a brief moment, the Enterprise was in the tachyon temporal stream in the 24th century.  Betwixt and between then and now.  The Borg had already gone back in time, had already succeeded in their assault and history was changed creating an all-Borg "Timeline B".  But the Enterprise plunged down the hole and thwarted the Borg, creating "Timeline C" which is what the new universe lives in.

Comment: @Blaze, okay, I can see that being the case.